# How do you automatically assign texture from T pose model to animated model

Tags: texturing

Hello im sort of new to blender , i have a bunch of alembic animations from maya , but exporting alembic means all the textures on the model are gone , is there a way to automatically assign all the textures again , since theres so many shots that needs to be repetitively re assigned the texture